# Firefox unresponsive while loading frame in Selenium

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, frame

Using Selenium with python, I am trying to automate my GUI that has a menu on the left pane and a content area on the right pane. Below are the versions being used:
Selenium: 2.42.1
Python:   2.7.8
Firefox: 28

When a menu is clicked on the left, a page is loaded in the content area. The menus are multi-level expandable like Windows explorer. You click on level 1 and level 2 menus appear. Similarly, when you click level 2 menu, you see level 3 menu.

I am able to go till level 3 in menus. At this level, there is a  screen name. When i click it, it is expected that the screen will open up in the content area to the right side of the page. But I am facing an issue here. The page in the content area does not load and firefox becomes unresponsive. I have to then manually kill firefox. Firebug shows that below format of the context area when i open the screen manually(without using Selenium):
    `[div id="contentArea"]
    [iframe id="main"]
        [html class="dj_gecko dj_contentbox"]
             dbody class="mainBody appworks tundra"]
                  [div id="mainBC"]
                       [div id="contentBC]
                            [div id="contentBottom"]
                                  [span class="dijit dijitReset dijitLeft dijitInline dijitButton"]
                                       [span class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitInline"]
                                             [span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode"]
                                                  [button id="insertButton" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents"] 
                                                        [span class="dijitReset]
                                                             [span id="insertButton_label]`

I want to click this insertButton in the content area but the frame is not loaded when I run it in Selenium.

Below is my python code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()=\"Diameter\"]").click() # These are menus - level 1
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[text()=\"Configuration\"]").click() # level 2
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()=\"Application Ids\"]").click() # level 3

try:                        
    print "before switch"
    self.driver.switch_to_frame(0)  # There is only one frame in Contet area
    print "after switch"
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#insertButton").click()
    print "after finding Insert"
    #WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[text()=\"Insert\"]"))).click()
    #driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()=\"Insert\"]").click()
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

There is no exception being caught but firefox stops responding. I also do not see “Unresponsive script” warnings in firefox. I suspected this as incompatible versions of Firefox, Python or Selenium. I reverified them on Selenium page but they seem to be compatible. I do not see "after finding insert" in log file.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be incompatible version of firefox. Finally I am using below versions and it works fine:
Firefox 24
Selenium 2.40
Python 2.7.8.